# Plotting 2D map coordinates to OpenGL 3D projection

Tags: c++, opengl, math, graphics, tesselation

I’m trying to convert a 2D map created in my map editor to a 3D plotting with OpenGL. This is my map generated in my map editor:

[image: Map editor]

Those vertices are relative to my Cartesian origin world coordinate (top up of the picture) and I’m applying this formula to convert it to an OpenGL object coordinate:

World size: 800x600

```
x = (X / 800) -0.5
y = (Y / 600) -0.5
```

Getting this result:

(First object face)

```
−0.48625, 0.068333333
0.12625, 0.07
0.12875, −0.481666667
−0.4875, −0.486666667
```

Plotting this vertex buffer in OpenGL, I got a very weird result. So how can I get a 3D model from those vertex positions? Like this picture:

[image: Box room]

I’m rendering OpenGL in triangles mode and using this example as the start point: https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/1.getting_started/7.4.camera_class/camera_class.cpp

Using the conversion formula + the Earcut tessellation (https://github.com/mapbox/earcut.hpp), I've finally got this rectangle rendering correctly inside OpenGL. With two planes with just the Z-axis different, now the problem is how to render its laterals since Earcut just works with 2D coordinates...

[image: Planes]

Comment: its somewhat unclear what are you asking. is it how to place and size the QUAD representing your map to cover screen? or how to create cube-based mesh from some 2D map array (empty space or textured cube) ... Why do you even need ear clipping?

Comment: I need the ear clipping because the user can draw more than 4 vertices, forming other things than quads. Like a hexagon for example, but it is up to the user draw in the 2D space.
Is it possible extrude this 2d mesh in 3d?

Comment: As you clarified I retracted the close vote and added answer with simple C++ example how I see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right you got some planar **2D** polygon and what to add some constant thickness to it (as a 3D mesh). That is doable fairly easily. As you correctly assumed you need to triangulate first. So you should have this input:

1. table of points `pnt[pnts]`

   list of all points of your object.
2. polygon `pol[pols]` (circumference of your object)

   just ordered list of points indexes referencing to table of points
3. triangulation result `fac[facs]`

   ordered list of 3 point indexes representing all the triangles.

Now to make a mesh from it we need to do this:

1. **copy all the points and extrude them by some translation.**

   all this new points will be added to current `pnt[pnts]` table. Do not forget to remember original table size `pnts0` as it will be needed later.
2. **copy/reverse the triangulation.**

   The opposite side of the triangulated polygon will be the same just in reverse polygon winding. So just copy it to `fac[facs]` as new triangles in reverse index order ... Do not forget to add the original point table size to all the new faces. This will use the new points ... From the images of yours you got to this point already.
3. **create the missing side faces.**

   For this we can exploit the original polygon. As we just copied the points then we know that `pnt[3*i]`  is opposite to `pnt[pnts0+3*i]`. So we just create triangle faces joining the opposite edges of the polygon.

Here small C++ example I busted for this right now:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int N=128;
int pnts=6*3;                   // 3* number of points
float pnt[N]=                   // x,y per each point
    {
    -0.5,-0.5,0.0,              //   6 ------ 9
    -0.4, 0.0,0.0,              //    +      +
    -0.5,+0.5,0.0,              //     3   12
    +0.5,+0.5,0.0,              //    +      +
    +0.4, 0.0,0.0,              //   0 ----- 15
    +0.5,-0.5,0.0,
    };
int pol[N]={ 0,3,6,9,12,15 }, pols=6; // original polygon (3*pnt index), number of its vertexes
int fac[N]=                     // triangulation result (3*pnt index)
    {
    0,3,15,
    3,12,15,
    3,6,12,
    6,9,12,
    }, facs=4*3;                // number of triangles*3
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void extrude(float dz)
    {
    int i,i0,pnts0=pnts;
    // copy and reverse triangulation
    for (i=0;i<facs;i++)
     fac[facs+facs-1-i]=fac[i]+pnts; facs+=facs;
    // duplicate points
    for (i=0;i<pnts;i++) pnt[pnts0+i]=pnt[i]; pnts+=pnts;
    // extrude points
    for (i=      2;i<pnts0;i+=3) pnt[i]-=dz;
    for (         ;i<pnts ;i+=3) pnt[i]+=dz;
    // side faces
    for (i0=pols-1,i=0;i<pols;i0=i,i++)
        {
        fac[facs]=pol[i ]+pnts0; facs++;
        fac[facs]=pol[i ];       facs++;
        fac[facs]=pol[i0];       facs++;

        fac[facs]=pol[i0]+pnts0; facs++;
        fac[facs]=pol[i ]+pnts0; facs++;
        fac[facs]=pol[i0];       facs++;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
/*
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,GL_FILL);
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK,GL_LINE);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
*/

    // set view
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
    static float ang=0.0;
    glRotatef(ang,0.2,0.7,0.1); ang+=5.0; if (ang>=360.0) ang-=360.0;

    // render mesh
    float *p0,*p1,*p2,n[3],a[3],b[3],c;
    glColor3f(0.7,0.7,0.7);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (int i=0;i+3<=facs;i+=3)
        {
        // points
        p0=pnt+fac[i+0];
        p1=pnt+fac[i+1];
        p2=pnt+fac[i+2];
        // compute normal
        a[0]=p1[0]-p0[0]; a[1]=p1[1]-p0[1]; a[2]=p1[2]-p0[2];
        b[0]=p2[0]-p1[0]; b[1]=p2[1]-p1[1]; b[2]=p2[2]-p1[2];
        n[0]=(a[1]*b[2])-(a[2]*b[1]);
        n[1]=(a[2]*b[0])-(a[0]*b[2]);
        n[2]=(a[0]*b[1])-(a[1]*b[0]);
        c=1.0/sqrt((n[0]*n[0])+(n[1]*n[1])+(n[2]*n[2]));
        n[0]*=c; n[1]*=c; n[2]*=c;
        // render
        glNormal3fv(n);
        glVertex3fv(p0);
        glVertex3fv(p1);
        glVertex3fv(p2);
        }
    glEnd();

//  glFlush();
    glFinish();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    // Init of program
    gl_init(Handle);    // init OpenGL
    extrude(0.2);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // Exit of program
    gl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // repaint
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // resize
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::tim_redrawTimer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is **VCL** based so ignore all the **VCL** stuff and port the events you want/need and **GL context** stuff to your style of programing. The only important stuff here are:

the tables `pnt,fac,pol` which holds the input and latter also output. The `extrude(dz)` will create the mesh (call it just once!) and gl_draw will render the tables as mesh (Using the old style **GL** api for simplicity).

For the GL stuff I used my `gl_simple.h` which you can find in this related QA:

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

Here is preview of the code above:

[image: preview]

the choppynes is due to my GIF capture the rendering is smooth. I used static allocation and on the run normal computation so the code is simple and easy to understand. Of coarse for the real deal you need to implement dynamic lists and VAO/VBO ... if you want good performance

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure, but it seems your object has only thwo faces rendered because you didn't add the other faces to the index.

Because you have your vertices, but you also need to tell have a triangles for the sides. If they are triangles you should end up with 16 triangles to draw.
If you don't use an index, you need to duplicate your vertices, for each triangle and end up with 48 vertices to draw.

As to get the earing algorithm to work in 3D, if you know for sure that your polygon has all it's point in the same plan, you can take 3 vertices, deduce it's plan, and create a transformation matrix to bring all these points to (x,y,0) which is like 2D coordinates.